# Display text from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to display a message in the `view` from the `controller`. Here's my code;

VIEW

```
@Html.LabelFor // How do i write the rest to display the message
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {

        // I Need to send a String to the Label in the View

        return View();
}
```

Comment: There are so many approaches including ViewBags and ViewData, but shockingly, you can also use a Model. Please do a good faith attempt yourself. This question can be answered too easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably the more elegant solution, when called for at least, is to use a strongly-typed view (with a model - the M in MVC). A simple example could be:

The model:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MessageViewModel {Message = "Hello from far away"};
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The view:

```
@model MyNamespace.MessageViewModel

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Message)</h2>
```

Would I bother with this for a single message on a page? Surprisingly, most of the time I would. There's something elegant about the view knowing exactly what to expect (and vice versa), Intellisense support, and the `HtmlHelper`'s `DisplayFor()` method where you can do all kinds of implicit formatting.

---

That being said, the "simplest" (read: quick and dirty, but gets ugly quick) solution would be to stuff your message into the `ViewBag` dynamic object.

In the controller:

```
ViewBag.MyMessage = "Hello from a far away place";
```

In the view:

```
@ViewBag.MyMessage
```

But doing this, you lose Intellisense, repeatability (DRY), and possibly your sanity. One property used in one place, maybe (*a la* `ViewBag.Title` that the default _Layout page uses). A whole bunch of disconnected objects stuffed in the bag, no thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping someone was going to mention making a model. That's definitely a preferred way. Also, in your previous edit you had a model of string and called `return View("Hello from a far away place.");`. This would have failed as the View(string) overload would have used that string to locate a view. If you want to pass the default view with a string as your model, you'd need to name the parameter: `return View(model: "Hello from a far away place.");`.

Comment: You will get my +1 if you remove the first part of your answer about the `ViewBag` stating that the only correct way to do this is to use a view model.

Comment: @Joshua You're completely right which is why I changed it to keep things simpler.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov For completeness I've kept it there, but changed the order and the tone a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Viewbag](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx) or viewdata in your controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       ViewData["listColors"] = colors;
        ViewData["dateNow"] = DateTime.Now;
        ViewData["name"] = "Hajan";
        ViewData["age"] = 25;;

        ViewBag.ListColors = colors; //colors is List
        ViewBag.DateNow = DateTime.Now;
        ViewBag.Name = "Hajan";
        ViewBag.Age = 25;
        return View(); 
    }
<p>
    My name is 
    <b><%: ViewData["name"] %></b>, 
    <b><%: ViewData["age"] %></b> years old.
    <br />    
    I like the following colors:
</p>
<ul id="colors">
<% foreach (var color in ViewData["listColors"] as List<string>){ %>
    <li>
        <font color="<%: color %>"><%: color %></font>
    </li>
<% } %>
</ul>
<p>
    <%: ViewData["dateNow"] %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{

        ViewBag.Message = "Hello World";

        return View();
}
```

Your view

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
```